# Require a full clean/rebuild prior to running a console application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a c# console application project in visual studio that should only be run:

- with the debugger attached
- and only after a full clean / rebuild

Is there a way to force the project to fail if hasn't had a full clean/rebuild prior to launch?

Background info: The application is used to deploy versions of another application. It gathers up everything that's needed from various sources including downloads, zips them and and places them in a version deployment system.

One of the sources it gathers up files from is the output directory of another project that it references. The full clean/rebuild is required to ensure that output directory contains the latest and correct binaries.

The REAL problem I'm trying to solve is making sure that we are deploying the latest and correct binaries from another project.

Comment: You may get a more appropriate answer if you provide details as to why the project must be run with the debugger attached after a full clean / rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for an application to know if it was built-clean is for it to inspect the rest of the files in the directory it lives in, how you do that is up to you (try using `FileInfo` and inspect the `LastWriteTime` property).

As for the debugger, try this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

...

public static Int32 Main(String[] args) {
    if( !Debugger.IsAttached ) {
        Console.WriteLine("No debugger attached. Execution will resume once a debugger is attached.");
        while( !Debugger.IsAttached ) Thread.Sleep( 100 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dai, I did use your suggestion about the file LastWriteTime ... it'll have to do until a better one is found :)